# Why are the 2 verbs in this sentence different tenses?

Tags: tense, verbs, sentence-structure

Why are the two verbs in this sentence in different tenses? Why is one in the past tense “interviewed” and “working” in present tense?

-The actor interviewed by Frank is working on a project in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

There is no past tense of any kind in the sentence.

The only finite verb is *is* (in *is working*).

*Interviewed* is a participle, and is not tensed.

The form is confusingly often referred to as the "past participle", but it has no inherent "past" in its meaning. Consider:

> He is being interviewed. (present).

> He will be interviewed tomorrow. (future).

> Everytime he lands in London he gets interviewed (habitual).

*Interviewed by Frank* is untensed - the event is probably in the past, but could be happening right now.